# Emacs vs subversion with passtype gpg-agent

Tags: version-control

I'm currently setting up a new Ubuntu box for myself at work. I generally have my work related stuff under subversion.

The default method for subversion to store passwords in Ubuntu seems to be `passtype = gpg-agent`. This works fine with `svn` on the command line. But if I want to commit from Emacs, it fails.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is using Emacs 25.2.2, if I run `M-x vc-print-log` I get an error similar to

```
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL https://svn....
svn: No more credentials or we tried too many times
```

If I use an account where the svn passtype is set to `simple` (aka plaintext password), Emacs has no issues.

Also, if I run `svn log file` first and then right after run `M-x vc-print-log` Emacs has no issues.

Any idea what is going on here, and how to fix it?

---

From looking at the sources (`vc-svn.el`) the default `--non-interactive` option, seems to be the problem. At least if I either change it to `--force-interactive` then it works. This that removing it also might be an option, will have to wait untill the last use is timed out.

Deleting the option does *not* solve the problem. But `--force-interactive` does.

Answer (score 1):

As is usually the case right after one posts a question, you'll find an answer elsewhere.

After looking in the sources (`lisp/vc/vs-svn.el`) we learn that unless under `darwin` `svn` will be given the `--non-interactive` option. This seems to be the problem when subversion is using the passtype `gpg-agent`. Changing it to `--force-interactive` works (deling it does not).

Comment: Please report the problem via `M-x report-emacs-bug`, thank you.